# How to  select all characters after a $ when the string coming in is always a different length

Tags: vb.net, string

The following string could be:   dsafk$asdlfdl or odldl$ldlkfjdsljfdslkjfdslkjf

I need to do the following.  Select everything to the rigt of the dollar sign, move it to the left of the dollar sign, and then put a second string that is coming into this function to the right of the dollar sign where the old string was.

Comment: Why can't you just strip out the dollar sign wherever it is, add a new dollar sign on the end, and append whatever you want to the right of it?  The [string API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wtc81z6.aspx) has a list of the methods you'll need for this.

Answer (score 3):

```
myString = myString.Replace("$", string.Empty) & "$" & passedString
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways to do string manipulation.  You'll want to add error checking and all that, but something like this should do the trick:

```
myString = string.Format("{0}{1}${2}", myString.Split("$")[0], myString.Split("$")[1], passedString)
```

or:

```
myString = string.Format("{0}${1}", myString.Replace("$", string.Empty), passedString)
```

and so on...

Comment: +1 But odd to use String.Format to do concatenation, rather than use the operator &

Comment: @MarkJ: Force of habit, I guess.  Again, there are multiple ways to do anything with strings.  Use `String.Concat()`, `StringBuilder`, etc.  If we're talking about a high volume application where performance tweaks are important, then mutability of the strings is something to think about as well in order to save a few bytes and clock cycles here and there.